# \section formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, section-titles

I am trying to format my \section command in order to get a result like :

[image]

"Partie" is a piece a text I want to see everytime. Then "1" corresponds to the section number, and "Introduction" to the section title.

I have found two differents things :

- A way to draw a line under "Partie 1" :

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={anchor=base,inner sep=0pt}]
\node[my node] (center) {Partie \thesection};
\draw($(center.base)+(-1.9cm,-1ex)$)     -- ($(center.base)+(+1.9cm,-1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

- A way to change the format of \section :

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\scshape}}
\makeatother
```

But I don't know how to mix those two ideas !

I'm using {book} documentclass.
Even though it looks like "Partie 1 Introduction" is on a full page, it is not supposed to be the case. It is only a centred \section title with a line under.

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Most LaTeX classes know a command called `\part` that may already be closer to what you want than `\section`.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Should "Partie 1 Introduction"  occupy a page on its own? If so, you might be interested in modifying the `\part` command instead.

Comment: Hi everyone ! Im using \documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{book}

Unfortunately I am already using \part and \chapter. But "Partie 1 Introduction" is not supposed to use a full page !

Comment: I am editing my post in order to add the documentclass I'm using and the fact that it is not supposed to use a full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

Do you really this head belongs as `\section`, not sure. Anyhow, hope the below `MWE` may helps you...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\textsc{Partie}\ \thesection\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}{1em}{}

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\textsc{Partie}\
\thesection\\\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}\\}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It is almost perfect : the line has to be 3cm wide : when I change "\textwidth" by "3cm", the line and "Introduction" are side to side... Any idea ?

Comment: @Guliup Check the `Update` suggestion...

Comment: Thats perfect !

Comment: @Guliup Glad to help you, if the suggestion suits with your requirement, then please accept the answer by clicking the `tick` mark...

Comment: It's me again : I'm trying to use your first code for \subsubsection's title. Here is my code : \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\textsc{Section}\ \thesubsubsection\\\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}{1em}{}
Do you know why it is not working ? It is only centring the subsubsection title.

Comment: @Guliup In `book` class file, it was defined as upto two level head should be numbered, from third level head onwards all the following head was unnumbered, hope it was your issue, try with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\textsc{Partie}\
\thesubsubsection\\\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}\\}{1em}{}
`

Comment: You are the best :)

Comment: @Guliup So many best pupil are here, I am not the best, I am one of a learner....Anyhow, thanks for your kind words... it will boost me...